# #REF! Error in excel when updating/changing data in another worksheet

Tags: excel

So i am creating a “template”. So in this workbook i have 2 sheets named “Template” and “WL”.

In “Template” worksheet, there is a table with formulas in each cell. This formula will get data from the “WL” worksheet. For example in one of the cell in the table (=COUNTIFS(WL!G:G,A6)), where i take data from worksheet WL column G.

Problem is, when i update the data in the “WL” sheet by replacing or deleting the current data, the table in “template” will have #REF! Error. Been knockin my head to get over this. Any solutions ?

Thanks !

Comment: Don't delete the cells, do not use cut/paste.  Use the `Delete` button to clear the values after copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

One solution, if you want to *keep* the reference to `WL!G:G`:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDIRECT("'WL!'G:G"),A6)
```

So even if you delete columns, etc. it'll keep looking at column G.

Comment: meh. INDIRECT is volatile.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep deleting columns instead of just replacing data in the existing columns, change your formula to use INDEX

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(WL!1:1048576,,7),A6)
```

Comment: meh, This is sort of volitile, in that _any_ change, _anywhere_ on sheet `WL` will trigger a recalc

Comment: @chrisneilsen then =COUNTIFS(INDEX(Sheet3!1:1,2):INDEX(Sheet3!999:999,2),A6)